# Phonegap-compatible code to play sounds in website HTML/JS pages?

Tags: javascript, cordova

How to code my website HTML5/JS page so my onclick sound-playing stays compatible with later Phonegap porting ?

Any tricks there ?

---

Edit: for those who love to play with jsfiddle, there is [a fiddle which the only value is its  play/stop icons and audiofile](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/wyhsU/)

```
  .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the Media object provided by PhoneGap/Cordova in its core.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

```
playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
```

or as below:

```
// Create Media object from src
my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

// Play audio
my_media.play();
```

Comment: Which one is the Phonegap code, which one is a pure JS code ? Does one will work both with and without phonegap.js ?

Comment: Both are related to PhoneGap. So they are dependent on PhoneGap. You would be able to still use them as you are using .js files